# SQL Server 2008 : group by , get max and sum up the values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table :

```
category    name    id  value   total   date
-----------------------------------------------
A         student   11  30       50    1-Jan-20
A         student   12  40       100   1-Jan-20
A         staff     16  50       50    1-Jan-20
B         student   14  30       50    1-Jan-20
B         student   15  60       100   1-Jan-20
C         staff     11  30       50    1-Jan-20
B         staff     18  30       50    1-Jan-20
B        master     20  40       100   1-Jan-20
```

Expected output :

```
name       value    total   date
-------------------------------------
student    100      200     1-Jan-20
staff       80      100     1-Jan-20
master      40      100     1-Jan-20
```

Logic :

1. Pick only the category : A, B
2. For each name under category A, B : pick the record with max(id)

   For example:

   ```
   A   student 12  40  100 1-Jan-20
   B   student 15  60  100 1-Jan-20
   ```
3. Then sum above records as below :

   student 100 200 1-Jan-20

Under progress query :

```
select sum(t.value), sum(t.total)
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by category order by id desc) as rn
  from [dbo].[Table_1]   
  where category in ('A', 'B')
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: So what is your question here exactly? What isn't working about your attempt?

Comment: Also, take the time to make your tabular data well formatted. It looks like people have names like `'11  30'` and `'15  60'` or a total value of `'100 200'`, which isn't a valid `int`, so can't be summed.

Comment: You are basically just missing the `group by` in the outer query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `name column` in `partition clause`

```
select name,sum(t.value), sum(t.total)
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by category,name order by id desc) as rn
  from [dbo].[Table_1]   
  where category in ('A', 'B')
) t
where t.rn = 1 group by name
```